# тестирование Selenium webDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Подскажите пожалуйста. Задача заключается в том чтобы открыть сайт `www.random.org`, нажать на кнопку `Numbers` - `Integers`. Потом нажать `Get Numbers` и цифры вывести в консоль. Работаю с `selenium webdriver`, java и intellige idea. 
Наткнулся на проблему, что не могу найти элемент через `cssSelector`.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Basic {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver webBrowser = new ChromeDriver();
        webBrowser.get("https://www.random.org/");

        webBrowser.findElement(By.cssSelector("ЧТО ТУТ ПИСАТЬ")).click();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если элемент имеет id="example", то написать

```
webBrowser.findElement(By.cssSelector("#example")).click();
```

Если элемент имеет class="example", то написать

```
webBrowser.findElement(By.cssSelector(".example")).click();
```

Обязательно прочитать [статью на сайте](https://kreisfahrer.gitbooks.io/selenium-webdriver/content/webdriver_api_slozhnie_vzaimodeistviya/lokatori_css,_xpath,_jquery.html) , иначе не удастся нормально работать.

Comment: спасибо разобрался с первой частью.

Comment: Теперь как вывести в консоль : System.out.println(webBrowser.findElements(By.cssSelector("pre[class='data']"))); но выводит какую-то ерунду. Что не так?

Comment: Если разобрались, то нужно пометить в качестве ответа и задать новый вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Подскажите пожалуйста. Задача заключается в том чтобы открыть сайт www.random.org, нажать на кнопку Numbers - Integers. Потом нажать Get Numbers и цифры вывести в консоль. Работаю с selenium webdriver, java и intellige idea. Наткнулся на проблему, что не могу вывести результат в консоль.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Basic {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver webBrowser = new ChromeDriver();
        webBrowser.get("https://www.random.org/");


        webBrowser.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='/#numbers']")).click();
        webBrowser.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='https://www.random.org/integers/']")).click();
        webBrowser.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value='Get Numbers']")).click();

        System.out.println(webBrowser.findElements(By.cssSelector("pre[class='data']")));
    }
}
```